# Требуется ли тире: "сначала крупные группы, потом мелкие"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Развиваются сначала крупные мышечные группы, потом мелкие.

Перед словом "мелкие" нужно тире или нет? Я предполагаю, что нет, так как в начале предложения слово "развиваются", которое относится и к крупным, и к мелким группам.

Answer (score 1):

**Развиваются сначала крупные мышечные группы, потом мелкие.**

Это предложение удобнее прочитать без паузы, не обозначая параллельной структуры, поэтому запятую не ставим:

В общем случае постановка тире в неполном предложении зависит от его интонационного членения и наличия пауз.

[Розенталь. § 6. Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93)

1) О, я хочу безумно жить, всё сущее — увековечить, безличное — вочеловечить, несбывшееся — воплотить! За окном вагона плыла кочковатая равнина, бежали кустарники, дальние — медленно, ближние — вперегонку (А. Т.);

2) Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леон.).

Также (похожий пример): **Сначала вешают крупные игрушки, затем мелкие.**